How to write the vector of i, j, k
I am trying to type the vector of i, j, k namely
The last one can be done satisfactorily by \vec{k}, the j version can also be typed as \vec{\textit{ȷ}} (I am typing all these in MathStackExchange, and somehow \j doesn’t work there). When I try the similar thing to \vec{\textit{ı}}, the i is not right below the arrow. What’s more wield is that, \vec{\!\textit{ı}} turns the arrow into a gigantic one, instead of normal vector arrow.\overset{\rightarrow}{\!\textit{ı}} doesn’t work either.
The best way I know is to write it as \overset{\boldsymbol\rightarrow}{\textbf{ı}}, which looks absolutely fine except it is bolded.
How do I write the vector as shown in the image that are not bold?

Please post your code, what you tried so far, note that it should be from \documentclass to \end{document}

\imath and \jmath are the standard latex math commands for dotless i and j

don't use \text.. commands to access math characters

@MadyYuvi As I said, I wrote things on MathStackExchange, and I am not sure how to write it as you wanted. All I know is to put $ around the command. I am an absolute beginner at LaTeX.

Note your image is misleading as it shows the arrows at the same height, but to get that you want a normal i and j to be the same height as k, not the dotless versions, see my answer.

@DavidCarlisle In fact, what I want is exactly like what is shown in the image. But your answer is good enough for me.

\imath and \jmath are the standard latex math commands for dotless i and j

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \vec{\imath}+\vec{\jmath}+\vec{k}+\vec{i}+\vec{j}
\]

\end{document}


They are not only standard LaTeX commands, they are defined in plain.tex too.

My comment is completely true. There is no need to attach an extensive polemic to it. It only adds an information to your sentence "\imath and \jmath are the standard latex math commands" (which is, of course, true too).

@wipet your comment was true but I think misleading, lots of things are true but that doesn't mean it makes sense to post them as comments under random questions.

Your sentence is comparably misleading. The only relevant from OP's point of view is that these commands can be used in MathJax.He doesn't care where these commands comes from (from TeX's perspective). If you wrote only: "\imath and \jmath can be used in MathJax" then I didn't add my comment.

so you would close as off topic? The question doesn't mention mathjax and gives examples of latex commands, and I gave a latex answer.
